# How can I set backgroundColor at only TableWidget's colmun?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to add color only to the left side of the table, but I have tried various methods and they do not work, as shown in the image below. How can I do this?

```dart
final informations = [
    {"title": "e-mail", "text": "xxxxxx@xxxx"},
    {"title": "phone number", "text": "111111111111"},
    {"title": "other", "text": "nothingnothingnothingnothingnothingnothingnothingnothingnothingnothingnothing"}
  ];

List<TableRow> getWidgets(List<Map<String, String>> infos) {
  final List<TableRow> listed = <TableRow>[];
  for (int i = 0; i < infos.length; i++) {
    listed.add(TableRow(children: [
      Container(color: Colors.blue.shade400,child: Text(infos[i]["title"])),
      Container(child: Text(infos[i]["text"]),)
    ]));
  }
  return listed;
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
final List<Map<String, String>> informations = [
    {"title": "e-mail", "text": "xxxxxx@xxxx"},
    {"title": "phone number", "text": "111111111111"},
    {
      "title": "other",
      "text":
          "nothingnothingnothingnothingnothingnothingnothingnothingnothingnothingnothing"
    }
  ];
  List<TableRow> getWidgets(List<Map<String, String>> infos) {
    final List<TableRow> listed = <TableRow>[];
    for (int i = 0; i < infos.length; i++) {
      listed.add(TableRow(children: [
        TableCell(
            verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.fill,
            child: Container(
                color: Colors.blue.shade400, child: Text(infos[i]["title"]))),
        TableCell(
          child: Container(child: Text(infos[i]["text"])),
        )
      ]));
    }
    return listed;
  }
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
It was displayed as expected. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Glad it worked for you, please accept the answer if it helped you solve your problem.